# How do I run a custom Annotation Processor in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I have an annotation `check.java` & annotation processor `CheckProcessor.java` that I've written and exported to a jar file `check.jar`.

I also have `Test.java` which is a small class to test the annotation. Running `javac -cp check.jar Test.java` works on the command line.

I can't get it to work in IntelliJ. I've added `check.jar` as an external library. The `@check` annotation can be used without compilation errors, but the annotation processor is never run.

I have enabled annotation processing under `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler` -> `Annotation Processors`, and provided a custom processor path straight to the jar file

Comment: how have you configured it all?

Comment: Is it registered via `META-INF/services` or in the `module-info.java`?

Comment: I've included a file `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.processor` which has one line `CheckProcessor` in the jar, does this need to be somewhere else?

Comment: Is `CheckProcessor` in the default package?

Comment: yes, I haven't specified a package in CheckProcessor.java

Comment: Does it work using packages?

Comment: I added `package checkAnnotation;` and moved `CheckProcessor` to `checkAnnotation/CheckProcessor`, and put `checkAnnotation.CheckProcessor` in `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.processor`, didn't work. But I know services are being registered at least, as I got compiler errors after I made a typo.